# How to locate a structured region of data inside of a not structured data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, data-cleaning

I have a certain kind of data frames that contain a subset of interest. **The problem is that this subset, is non consistent between the different data frames**. Nonetheless, *in a more abstract level*, follows a general structure: **a rectangular region inside the data frame.**

```
example1 <- data.frame(x = c("name", "129-2", NA, NA, "acc", 2, 3, 4, NA, NA), 
       y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "deb", 3, 2, 5, NA, NA),
       z = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "asset", 1, 1, 2, NA, NA))

print(example1)

      x    y     z
1   name <NA>  <NA>
2  129-2 <NA>  <NA>
3   <NA> <NA>  <NA>
4   <NA> <NA>  <NA>
5    acc  deb asset
6      2    3     1
7      3    2     1
8      4    5     2
9   <NA> <NA>  <NA>
10  <NA> <NA>  <NA>
```

The `example1` contain a **clear rectangular región** with a structure information:

```
5    acc  deb asset
6      2    3     1
7      3    2     1
8      4    5     2
```

As mentioned before, the region is not always consistent,

1. *the position of the columns are not always the same*
2. *the name of the variables insde the subset of interest are not always the same*

Here another `example2`:

```
example2 <- data.frame(x = c("name", "129-2", "wallabe #23", NA, NA, "acc", 2, 3, 4, NA ), 
       y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "balance", "deb", 3, 2, 5, NA),
       z = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "asset", 1, 1, 2, NA),
       u = c(NA, NA, NA, "currency:", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
       i = c(NA, NA, NA, "USD", "result", "win", 2, 3, 1, NA),
       o = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "lose", 2, 2, 1, NA))

print(example2)
> example2
            x       y     z         u      i    o
1         name    <NA>  <NA>      <NA>   <NA> <NA>
2        129-2    <NA>  <NA>      <NA>   <NA> <NA>
3  wallabe #23    <NA>  <NA>      <NA>   <NA> <NA>
4         <NA>    <NA>  <NA> currency:    USD <NA>
5         <NA> balance  <NA>      <NA> result <NA>
6          acc     deb asset      <NA>    win lose
7            2       3     1      <NA>      2    2
8            3       2     1      <NA>      3    2
9            4       5     2      <NA>      1    1
10        <NA>    <NA>  <NA>      <NA>   <NA> <NA>
```

The `example2` contain a **not clear rectangular región**:

```
6          acc     deb asset      <NA>    win lose
7            2       3     1      <NA>      2    2
8            3       2     1      <NA>      3    2
9            4       5     2      <NA>      1    1
```

One method to scan this dataframe to locate this kind of region inside of it?

*Any idea is appreciated*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try the longest sequence with same amount of `NA`s:

```
findTable <- function(df){
  naSeq <- rowSums(is.na(df))          # How many NA per row
  myRle <- rle(naSeq )$length          # Find sequences length
  df[rep(myRle == max(myRle), myRle),] # Get longest sequence
}

findTable(example1)
    x   y     z
5 acc deb asset
6   2   3     1
7   3   2     1
8   4   5     2

findTable(example2)
    x   y     z    u   i    o
6 acc deb asset <NA> win lose
7   2   3     1 <NA>   2    2
8   3   2     1 <NA>   3    2
9   4   5     2 <NA>   1    1
```

Comment: Brilliant approach! Can you explain me a little bit more this part of the function `myRle <- rle(rs)$length` " ?    It didn't work when I used it with the examples. Thx!