# Splitting a dataframe into parts by detection, then writing to multiple csv's?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, split

I have a csv as shown in the image below. The data is a set of separate tables, separated by a blank line, that I require to be in separate csv files.

After importing to R, I'd like to split the data into the various separate tables, and then write these tables to separate csv files. I had the idea of using some kind of string detect, as a 'new' table is signified by the first instance of 'Area' in the first column. Any ideas of how to approach the code for this in R? There are a bunch of tables and doing this manually isn't advisable.

There's a truncation problem too it seems, as the tables will be required to have a differing amounts of columns, however I don't expect that getting rid of NULL or NA data should be too difficult with this.

Thanks for any help.

[image: data]

Comment: still unclear about the basis on which to split

Comment: @joel.wilson i'd like to split such that the different tables in the image are separated.

Comment: Can you share the example in csv form?

Comment: I had a similar problem, only that I wanted one structured table. Look the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007903/how-to-locate-a-structured-region-of-data-inside-of-a-not-structured-data-frame), the `findTable` function, maybe you can adapt the solution into something like seek and extract, then iterate that process, until you have all the tables.

Comment: Place your .xlsx file to web so that I can do it with that as well.

Comment: With the proper assignment by taking into account different no. of rows, you get no `NA` or `NULL` value. See the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should take each different table to the uppermost part. All in all, you have 5 tables with different dimensions (Table1: 11x13; Table2: 11x9; Table3: 3x12; Table4: 10x5; Table5: 6x7). Take them side-by-side in the above (A1:M11; N1:V11 etc.). The headings of tables would be in 1st row.

```
library(readxl)
# Use the path returned from getwd() function that is R's working directory
df <- as.data.frame(read_excel("C://Users//User//Documents//Revolution//Your.xlsx"))
```

Then, you can handle these 5 tables as:

```
Table1 <- df[,1:13]
Table2 <- df[,14:22]
Table3 <- df[1:3,23:34]
Table4 <- df[1:10,35:39]
Table5 <- df[1:6,40:46]
```

By caring dimensions stemmed from different row numbers in the assignmets, you do not face any `NA` or `NULL` value in Table1...Table5.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think R is the right tool for this kind of thing.  You should always try to use the right tool based on the task.  Since you have Excel installed run this VBA script.  That will do what you want.

```
Sub page_endings()
    Dim i As Long 'how many times for pagebreak
    Dim searchvalue_for_break_after 'value to do pagebreak
    searchvalue_for_break_after = ""
     'column A must be filled in with value break after
     'example row 6, 12, 18, 24 whatever row you want
     'will loop until empty row in column A
    For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If Range("A" & i).Value = searchvalue_for_break_after Then
             'will add a pagebreak after the row with value break after
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add before:=Range("A" & i).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next i
    Call Create_Separate_Sheet_For_Each_HPageBreak
End Sub


Sub Create_Separate_Sheet_For_Each_HPageBreak()

    Dim HPB As HPageBreak
    Dim RW As Long
    Dim PageNum As Long
    Dim Asheet As Worksheet
    Dim Nsheet As Worksheet
    Dim Acell As Range

    'Sheet with the data, you can also use Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Asheet = ActiveSheet

    If Asheet.HPageBreaks.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no HPageBreaks"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'When the macro is ready we return to this cell on the ActiveSheet
    Set Acell = Range("A1")

    'Because of this bug we select a cell below your data
    'http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;210663
    Application.Goto Asheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count), True

    RW = 1
    PageNum = 1

    For Each HPB In Asheet.HPageBreaks
        'Add a sheet for the page
        With Asheet.Parent
            Set Nsheet = Worksheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        End With

        'Give the sheet a name
        On Error Resume Next
        Nsheet.Name = "Page " & PageNum
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Change the name of : " & Nsheet.Name & " manually"
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Copy the cells from the page into the new sheet
        With Asheet
            .Range(.Cells(RW, "A"), .Cells(HPB.Location.Row - 1, "K")).Copy _
                    Nsheet.Cells(1)
        End With
        ' If you want to make values of your formulas use this line also
        ' Nsheet.UsedRange.Value = Nsheet.UsedRange.Value

        RW = HPB.Location.Row
        PageNum = PageNum + 1
    Next HPB

    Asheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Application.Goto Acell, True

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    Call SaveWorksheetsAsCsv
End Sub


Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()

Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long

CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
' Store current details for the workbook
SaveToDirectory = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\"
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Sheets(WS.Name).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
' Temporarily turn alerts off to prevent the user being prompted
'  about overwriting the original file.

End Sub
```